# How can i relate a checkbox whit an Id in a Qtable Widget

Tags: python, pyside6

In my program i have,this page with two tables like this:
[image: Page two table´s]

And everytime e checked one row, the row pass to the table above.
What i want to know if is one way to relate the IdTeste with the checkbox because in the table above i will need the Id to make changes on a table in Postgresql.
I dont know what part of the code i should post were, but this is the part when i insert the data on the second table:

```
`def preenchetabel(self):`
    `con = psycopg2.connect()`

    
  `  cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM "Teste" """)
    num_rows9= cursor.rowcount
    num_columns9 = len(cursor.description)`


   
   ` cursor.execute("""SELECT       
                   "Teste"."IdTeste",
                   "Teste"."DataEntrada",
                   "Teste"."Código de Barras",
                   "Teste"."Numero de serie",
                   "Categorias"."NomeCategoria",
                   "Marcas"."NomeMarca",
                   "Teste"."Modelo",
                   "Fornecedores"."NomeFornecedor",
                   "Estado"."NomeEstado",
                   "Projetos"."NomeProjeto",
                   "Teste"."Valor/Uni",
                   "Teste"."Quantidade",
                   "Teste"."DataSaida"
                   FROM "Teste"
                   JOIN "Categorias" ON "Teste"."Categoria" = "Categorias"."IdCategoria"
                   JOIN "Marcas" ON "Teste"."Marcasss" = "Marcas"."IdMarca"
                   JOIN "Fornecedores" ON "Teste"."Fornecedores" = "Fornecedores"."IdFornecedor"
                   JOIN "Estado" ON "Teste"."Estado" = "Estado"."IdEstado"
                   JOIN "Projetos" ON "Teste"."Projeto" = "Projetos"."IdProjeto";""")
    dados = cursor.fetchall`
    
    `for row in range(num_rows9):
        for col in range(num_columns9):
            item = QTableWidgetItem("")
            self.tableLinhaNova.setItem(row, col, item)
            self.tableLinhaNova.setRowCount(0)
            self.tableLinhaNova.setColumnCount(12) 
    self.tableProdutossaida.setRowCount(num_rows9)`

    `self.tableProdutossaida.setColumnCount(num_columns9)`


   ` self.tableProdutossaida.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["CheckBox","IdTeste","Data de Entrada","Código de barras","Número de Série","Categoria","Marca","Descrição/Modelo","Fornecedor","Estado","Projeto","Valor/uni","Quantidade","DataSaida"])`
   
   ` for row_idx, row_data in enumerate(dados()):`
      
       ` checkbox = QCheckBox()
        checkbox.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.handleCheckbox)
        self.tableProdutossaida.setCellWidget(row_idx, 0, checkbox)`
        

      `
        for col_idx, cell_value in enumerate(row_data):`
          
            item = QTableWidgetItem(str(cell_value))
            self.tableProdutossaida.setItem(row_idx, col_idx + 1, item)

 
    for row_idx, row_data in enumerate(dados()):

        col_idx_after_removal = 0
        for col_idx, cell_value in enumerate(row_data):

            if col_idx not in num_columns9:
                # Criar um item para a célula
                item = QTableWidgetItem(str(cell_value))
                self.tableProdutossaida.setItem(row_idx, col_idx_after_removal, item)
                col_idx_after_removal += 1 `
```

If relate the id whit a checkbox isn´t possible how can i hide the id from the user and the Id still be in the row